# Is FileInfo.CopyTo / File.Copy guaranteed to succeed?

Tags: .net, file-io

By "guaranteed to succeed" I mean: If no Exception is thrown on the call to CopyTo, can I safely assume that the file was copied perfectly, or would it be reasonable to validate the copy (such as with a checksum)? This of course assumes that the integrity of the file is mission-critical.

Comment: I know it's pointless for you now, but I would say no. I get no Exceptions thrown and the file is not copied. My guess at this point is insufficient rights or the fact they are using AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be closed.  You can be sure that anyone else attempting to read the file will get a complete file.  But you can't be sure that all data buffers have been flushed to disk, so in the event of e.g. a system crash data could be lost.